# Chrome now prompting PDF security warning

Tags: mac, google-chrome, adobe-acrobat

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Google Chrome Annoying Download warning](https://superuser.com/questions/111674/google-chrome-annoying-download-warning)

It seems like there has been a recent change to chrome.  Now when I download a pdf I get a security warning.  Is there a way to add PDFs to a trusted list?

Comment: Are you referring to the 'Save/Discard' prompt? Chrome rightly considers PDFs to be executable files, as they're able to host Javascript and prompts just as it would for .exe or .zip files.

Comment: Mind giving a screenshot? I don't see this.

Comment: @Wesley They can hold those demons but would probably needlessly scare Joe Sixpack more than it would help.

Comment: @digitxp - I don't think it's a great idea, either, but then again there's a an awful lot of hyperlinks out there which point to PDF targets.

Comment: Can you please provide more concrete examples, including a screenshot?

Comment: Screenshot - http://i.imgur.com/gvWVY.png

Comment: Related to: http://superuser.com/questions/111674/google-chrome-annoying-download-warning