# How do I get chrome to stop prompting me when downloading PDFs?

Tags: google-chrome

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Google Chrome Annoying Download warning](https://superuser.com/questions/111674/google-chrome-annoying-download-warning)

Chrome warns me every time I download a PDF from Gmail and I always click 'Save'.  Is there any way to stop this warning?

[image]

Comment: Dupe [Chrome now prompting PDF security warning](http://superuser.com/questions/220834/chrome-now-prompting-pdf-security-warning) & Related [Google Chrome Annoying Download warning](http://superuser.com/questions/111674/google-chrome-annoying-download-warning)

Comment: done @MichaelPryor

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently there is no way to remove the warning. There is however an ongoing [discussion about it](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=9044) on the chromium issue tracker (open source project behind Chrome).

You can instead force Chrome to ask you where to save the file (Chrome Options -> Under the hood) and right-click links then choose "save as".

Comment: The bug is marked “fixed” but it is not clear what the fix was, since the problem persists in version 24.