# Why does Chrome confirm unnecessarily while downloading?

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I get chrome to stop prompting me when downloading PDFs?](https://superuser.com/questions/247063/how-do-i-get-chrome-to-stop-prompting-me-when-downloading-pdfs)

While downloading some .exe files Chrome confirms whether to **Keep** or **Discard** by asking "This type of file can harm your computer.Do you want to keep...?". For executables this behaviour is okay. But even for downloading some PDF files why does chrome confirm(as in the image)? Is there any way to suppress this behaviour?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is done for your safety. PDFs can infect you computer with malware as well as an exe file. 
You can not turn this off. The only workaround is to make chrome ask you where to save the file on every download.

Comment: You are correct. PDFs can also infect. But Chrome does confirm even for the files from trusted sites. That behaviour is annoying.

Comment: Chrome does a lot of annoying things in the name of security. If it weren't for the fact that it synchronizes my tabs between my tablet, my phone, and my computer, I would have switched back to Firefox long ago.