# How can I disable the "Files of this type can damage your computer" warning when downloading PDFs from a safe site?

Tags: google-chrome, security-warning

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Google Chrome Annoying Download warning](https://superuser.com/questions/111674/google-chrome-annoying-download-warning)

I need to download about 100-200 PDFs from a safe site (archive of a computer magazine). Clicking "Keep" 200 times is boring and I prefer the computer doing boring work for me, especially when it means hunting a moving button with my mouse.

Is there a way to make Chrome/Chromium shut up and just download the **** file?

Comment: Duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/465793/why-does-chrome-confirm-unnecessarily-while-downloading, http://superuser.com/questions/247063/how-do-i-get-chrome-to-stop-prompting-me-when-downloading-pdfs, http://superuser.com/questions/220834/chrome-now-prompting-pdf-security-warning, http://superuser.com/questions/111674/google-chrome-annoying-download-warning

Comment: This isn't possible (yet) but this answer describes a workaround: http://superuser.com/a/418950/6813