# Google Chrome - PDF Download - Warning

Tags: google-chrome

Why does Google Chrome sometimes warn that a PDFthat you are downloading can harm your computer?

Comment: [Google Chrome Annoying Download warning](http://superuser.com/q/111674)

Comment: Becaise downloading a pdf embedded with malware can harm your computer?  Your question is like why is the sky blue.

Answer (score 4):

Malicious code can be embedded in pdfs and infect your computer. You should only download pdfs if you trust their source.